# update each value for particular column key of array using foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to change all the quantity fields to the value: 1 for each member of my array but my attempt is returning undefined!

```js
var array = [{
  "quantity": 3,
  "line_item_id": 2140047343716,
  "location_id": null,
  "restock_type": "no_restock",
  "price": "30000.00",
  "subtotal": "90000.00",
  "total_tax": "15000.00",
  "discounted_price": "30000.00",
  "discounted_total_price": "90000.00",
  "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
}, {
  "quantity": 2,
  "line_item_id": 2140047310948,
  "location_id": null,
  "restock_type": "no_restock",
  "price": "81.92",
  "subtotal": "163.84",
  "total_tax": "27.31",
  "discounted_price": "81.92",
  "discounted_total_price": "163.84",
  "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
}]


var refundItems = array.forEach(element => {
  element.quantity = 1
})
console.log(refundItems);
```

I have done forEach loops before and I thought this would work, am I missing something obvious?

UPDATE -- >

I thought I'd update and be more specific with my scenario, the array was coming through as props in a react application (Imagine 'array' as props.refunds':

```
const FinalMessage = (props) => {
```

For this reason I would need to write a new array (I think) because I then wanted to assign the data into this object:

```
        let data = {
        domain: props.domain,
        customer_details: props.data.orderInfo,
        shipping: props.data.resdata.result.refund.shipping,
        refund_line_items: array,
        transactions: props.data.resdata.result.refund.transactions
    }
```

If I tried the forEach which didn't return anything then it would still use the original data.

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: This should work - it's just that `forEach` doesn't return anything (hence the `undefined`). It should have updated the array though - have you checked this?

Comment: What do I return?

Comment: I can't check it because it consoles undefined

Comment: you don't need to return anything. Just keep what you have (but you can remove the `var refundItems = ` since it's not needed), if you `console.log(array)` instead of `refundItems` you should see that your array has been updated as you want.

Comment: @Sparlarva you don't need to return anything, your `.forEach` mutates the array in-place. If you do `console.log(array)` you'd see it's updated.

Comment: I just saw your edit about this coming from the `props` in React. In this case, updating with `forEach` is definitely the wrong tool, because [props in Reach are supposed to be treated as read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

Answer (score 4):

`map` returns an array of anything you return from within itself i.e the element with the edited quantity.

`forEach` loops over the given array but does not expect to be returned out of and will not return anything.

To build a new Array of edited items in `refundItems` using map but avoid mutating original array.

```js
var array = [{
  "quantity": 3,
  "line_item_id": 2140047343716,
  "location_id": null,
  "restock_type": "no_restock",
  "price": "30000.00",
  "subtotal": "90000.00",
  "total_tax": "15000.00",
  "discounted_price": "30000.00",
  "discounted_total_price": "90000.00",
  "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
}, {
  "quantity": 2,
  "line_item_id": 2140047310948,
  "location_id": null,
  "restock_type": "no_restock",
  "price": "81.92",
  "subtotal": "163.84",
  "total_tax": "27.31",
  "discounted_price": "81.92",
  "discounted_total_price": "163.84",
  "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
}]

var refundItems = array.map(element => ({...element, quantity: 1}))

console.log(refundItems)
console.log(array)
```

Using `forEach`

```js
var array = [{
  "quantity": 3,
  "line_item_id": 2140047343716,
  "location_id": null,
  "restock_type": "no_restock",
  "price": "30000.00",
  "subtotal": "90000.00",
  "total_tax": "15000.00",
  "discounted_price": "30000.00",
  "discounted_total_price": "90000.00",
  "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
}, {
  "quantity": 2,
  "line_item_id": 2140047310948,
  "location_id": null,
  "restock_type": "no_restock",
  "price": "81.92",
  "subtotal": "163.84",
  "total_tax": "27.31",
  "discounted_price": "81.92",
  "discounted_total_price": "163.84",
  "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00"
}]

const refundItems = [] 
array.forEach(element => {
  refundItems.push({...element, quantity: 1})  
})

console.log(refundItems)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you just want the "new" array, but it leaves the old one unchanged. It's worth noting this for the OP because it's not clear whether they want to update the array in place (which their solution does) or make a new modified one alongside it (which yours does).

Comment: if the OP had the forEach loop not assigned to a variable i would have had a different response but as the loop is assigned to a variable i assumed the variable needed to be set so used a map.

Comment: @RobinZigmond this solution **does** change the original array, as well. It also copies it (with the changes) into a new array.

Comment: @VLAZ - oops, you're right that it does. I'd missed that. I think that marks it down in my opinion then, I wouldn't expect using `.map` to mutate the array (or to have to check the code carefully to see whether it does), and if that's the aim then I think using `forEach` is better.

Comment: Ok @VLAZ & Robin have updated answer based on your comments! thanks!

Comment: @FrancisLeigh you got it backwards.  Use `forEach` to modify each object, use `map` with the spread operator to create the new array.

Comment: Works fine for me on FF and should be fine, try refreshing browser.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` does not return a value. You can manipulate your objects in the `forEach` loop on the array of objects. So if this is what you want, you can do it like so

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```js
const array = [
  {
    "quantity" : 5,
    "somekey" : 'somekey'
  },
  {
    "quantity" : 10,
    "somekey2" : 'somekey2'
  }
]


array.forEach(element => element.quantity = 1)
console.log(array);
```

If you do not want to change your initial array, do it with `map` and use the `spread ...` syntax  ( or `Object.assign()` ) to duplicate the object. You need to duplicate your object because while `map` creates a new array, changing an object property value also changes the object inside the 'old' array.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const array = [
  {
    "quantity" : 5,
    "somekey" : 'somekey'
  },
  {
    "quantity" : 10,
    "somekey2" : 'somekey2'
  }
]
const newArray = array.map(obj => {
  return {
    ...obj, // use spread to duplicate the original object
    'quantity' : 1
    }
})
console.log(newArray,'newArray')
console.log(array,'oldArray')
```

Comment: "*If you do not want to change your initial array, do it with `map`*" your implementation does mutate the objects, though.

Comment: @VLAZ changed answer

Answer (score 0):

As per your question,You have not specified that you want new array of updated values or same array with updated values.

First of all, as per the forEach defination of javascript, forEach always returns **undefined**. It will not return anything. So you will not get anything in **refundItems**.

***Below code will change the values of original array variable on which forEach iterate.***

```js
var array = [{
"quantity":3,
"line_item_id":2140047343716,
"location_id":null,
"restock_type":"no_restock",
"price":"30000.00",
"subtotal":"90000.00",
"total_tax":"15000.00",
"discounted_price":"30000.00",
"discounted_total_price":"90000.00",
"total_cart_discount_amount":"0.00" } ,
{"quantity":2,
"line_item_id":2140047310948,
"location_id":null,
"restock_type":"no_restock",
"price":"81.92",
"subtotal":"163.84",
"total_tax":"27.31",
"discounted_price":"81.92",
"discounted_total_price":"163.84",
"total_cart_discount_amount":"0.00"
}]

array.forEach(element => {
  element.quantity = 1
})
console.log(array);
```

So instead of taking values in another variable and use that variable into console, use **array** variable itself and you will get your desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You can `push` elements inside your foreach:

```js
var array = [{"quantity":3,"line_item_id":2140047343716,"location_id":null,"restock_type":"no_restock","price":"30000.00","subtotal":"90000.00","total_tax":"15000.00","discounted_price":"30000.00","discounted_total_price":"90000.00","total_cart_discount_amount":"0.00"},{"quantity":2,"line_item_id":2140047310948,"location_id":null,"restock_type":"no_restock","price":"81.92","subtotal":"163.84","total_tax":"27.31","discounted_price":"81.92","discounted_total_price":"163.84","total_cart_discount_amount":"0.00"}]


var refundItems = []
array.forEach(element => {
  element.quantity = 1
  refundItems.push(element)
})

console.log(refundItems);
```

Comment: I think, you simulated .map method

Comment: @R3tep moreover, it still mutates the existing array, so it's not even a good `.map` substitute.

Comment: I think this is what `map` does

Comment: _map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so)._ See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)